# Interactivity between multiple sessions of a single running R Shiny app

Tags: r, interactive, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I would like to build an R Shiny app that is able to pass information from one running instance to other possible running instances. I have so far found nothing that could help me with this, and I'm hoping to do it right instead of resorting to global variables and/or writing to files etc (I used global variable in my example below, which I know is a bad practice; and I suspect writing to files wouldn't be a good practice either).

So for example, suppose I have my App.R running on a server and *Tim*, *Jack* and *John* have it open. How to make *Tim* see the below, when *Jack* and *John* are also using the app simultaneously and press the button as indicated in the below example?

**App.R:**

```
library(shiny)

# Somehow interactively visible variable? (I know global variables are bad, I wouldn't want to use such)
txt <<- ""

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        textInput("name", "User name", value="USERNAME"),
        actionButton("button", "Button"),
        htmlOutput("text")
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session){
        a <- eventReactive(input$button, {
            txt <<- paste(txt, "Button pressed by", input$name, "at", Sys.time(), "<br>")
            txt

        })
        output$text <- reactive({
            HTML(a())
        })
    }
)
```

Example desired output after multiple button presses from the respective users who all have an app instance running in their browsers (all had unique input$name selected but obviously an unique session id would be better):

[image: Example user case]

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can have sessions interact with eachildren other, but I have built a few applications that write events to a database. Certain actions in the application will recall the queries and pull any new changes made by other concurrent users.

Comment: That seems like a possible solution, though I was hoping there would be some way to interact directly. I guess I might have to build some SQL-based solution as well to pass on the information, that's definitely one way to do it even if goes beyond R Shiny. Need to give it some thought, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tested your code on a shiny server instance and it works as expected: i.e I get a printout similar to the one one you ask for.

I am a bit confused re: what are you exactly looking for?

Anyway, as a general comment I would disagree that using `<<-` is wrong or that `global variables` (in general or in a shiny app) are *bad*.

They have their place and indeed a typical use case is to pass states across sessions / users.

An alternative is to use `shiny`  `reactiveValues` as in:

```
 values <- reactiveValues()
 values$lognames <- ''
 ...
 ui <- (...)

 server <- function(input, output, session){

 a <- eventReactive(input$button, {
 values$lognames <- paste(values$lognames, "Button pressed by", input$name, "at", Sys.time(), "<br>")
 values$lognames
 })
...
 }
```

But as a general note of caution, this type of design, although possible, may ultimately bring *statefulness* to the app, quickly rising its complexity and kind of going against the simplicity of the `reactive` paradigm.

My strong recommendation is to really think carefully before every step on this road.  I've had the experience of implementing shiny apps that have rapidly escalated in complexity with the proliferation of these `states`. I had to keep track of all the states changes leading to brittle, difficult to debug apps.

Comment: Hello, thanks - the code works but the problem was, that each of those messages should've been sent by a separate running entity of the R Shiny App. Let's say "Tim" would live in an another country and his input$name is just indicated as above, and he's running his App. Then somebody else by the name "John" is using the App simultaneously (e.g. from an another country), and I want to be able to sent information between those separate sessions; for example, let's say for example that I want to build a real-time chat-room for multiple people using R Shiny by passing their text messages around.

Comment: Jeff Allen, RStudio employee and shiny server developer has an example of chat room here: https://github.com/trestletech/ShinyChat/blob/master/server.R. This is where I learned to use `reactiveValues`!

Comment: Thanks, that definitely sounds promising! :) gotta check it out