# Can a reactive data be seen by all server function in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

According to the shiny doc, the global variable can be seen, but can't be altered by shinyUI (reactive) actions.

I am wondering if there is a way to make variable be reactive, and seen but all server functions, without re-process the data inside each server function?

```
DT <- data.table(X = 1:10000,
                 Y = 10000:1,
                 Z = 30000:20001)
```

that is the original data file, and within each server function,  the `DT` will be processed first (same for each), then do some other things within the functions.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  A <- renderDataTable(
    DT[X > input$i.A & Y < input$i.B][,.(X, Z)]
  )

  B <- renderDataTable(
    DT[X > input$i.A & Y < input$i.B][,.(Y, Z)]
  )
}
```

Can I make something like this?

```
# be reactive outside of the box, and still can be seen by all
DT <- DT[X > input$i.A & Y < input$i.B]


# Just grasp the processed material
server <- function(input, output) {
  A <- renderDataTable(
    DT[,.(X, Z)]
  )

  B <- renderDataTable(
    DT[,.(Y, Z)]
  )
}
```

Comment: No, you can't. What is the use case for this? How would you handle conflicting inputs from multiple users?

Comment: Related - [Interactivity between multiple sessions of a single running R Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316659/interactivity-between-multiple-sessions-of-a-single-running-r-shiny-app)

Comment: indeed, I am thinking of the same thing. Doing so is because I have a really big table to handle at each reactive action. If I do the data manipulation, that would take lot of time, so I am wondering if I can process the data before hand. However, you are right, since everytime it was changed, it is not what it was, and the data is actually shrinking, and cause more problems. Thanks.

Comment: @Shree I do agree with you that rude action, like `<<-` will arouse more confusions in the near future. Seems I have to bring more RAM for the sake of time-saving. ;-(

Comment: Depending on the size of your data, one option would be to pre-calculate all possibilities and simply pull the appropriate subset into the app using `selectInput()`. This way there's no need to run an expensive calculation in real-time.